# Subscription of users who are not active for quite some days (2 or 3 months) is changed to none automatically in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

Consider the below scenarios:

There is one user "A" registered with the ejabberd server and is inactive for past 2 or 3 months.
There is another user "B" registered with the ejabberd server and has "A" in his/contact. User "B" not able to see the status of the "A". The user "A" is getting "auth-forbidden" in response of status query of user "A".

In the roster of user "B", the subscription of user "A" is coming none and in the roster of user "A" the subscription of all users under it are coming none.

Refer the attached screenshot for the user "A" roster.

Now my question is why the subscription of all contacts in user "A" roster is changed to none. User "A" is not active for couple of months, is there any configuration from which ejabberd marks the subscriptions of all contacts of inactive user to "none" ? How to change this configuration if such setting or configuration exists or there is some other issue in it?

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd does not have such a feature and ejabberd never change subscription. This should be something that is done in your own database or backend.